# How to check if distutils are installed and used properly?

Tags: python

I am using [NeuroNER](https://github.com/Franck-Dernoncourt/NeuroNER)

Unfortunately,I have problem to run
python main.py
NeuroNER version: 1.0-dev

```
TensorFlow version: 1.10.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 250, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 245, in main
    nn = NeuroNER(**arguments)
  File "/home/milenko/NeuroNER-master/src/neuroner.py", line 256, in __init__
    parameters, conf_parameters = self._load_parameters(arguments['parameters_filepath'], arguments=arguments)
  File "/home/milenko/NeuroNER-master/src/neuroner.py", line 95, in _load_parameters
    nested_parameters = utils.convert_configparser_to_dictionary(conf_parameters)
NameError: name 'utils' is not defined
```

AFter reading github 
[issue](https://github.com/Franck-Dernoncourt/NeuroNER/issues/75)
I changed neuroner.py line to

```
import distutils.util
```

but it does not help.
If I go for

```
sudo apt-get install python3-distutils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-distutils is already the newest version (3.6.5-3).
```

How to ckeck distutils package?

```
If I go for
apt-cache show distutils
N: Unable to locate package distutils
E: No packages found
```

But

```
apt-cache show python3-distutils
Package: python3-distutils
Architecture: all
Version: 3.6.5-3
Multi-Arch: foreign
Priority: optional
Section: python
Source: python3-stdlib-extensions
Origin: Ubuntu
```

ANyway import distutils is noot working.

Is there any command analogous to pip show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have an issue with `distutils`. The name to be defined is `utils`. So doing `import distutils.util` will never fix that issue.

If you look at the source, there's a `utils.py` module with the `convert_configparser_to_dictionary` function defined. You can see that [here](https://github.com/Franck-Dernoncourt/NeuroNER/blob/master/src/utils.py).

Try `import utils` instead. This will define the name `utils`, and it should work as expected. Note: I cannot test this.

HTH.